# Having issue returning data in django templates

Tags: django, django-views

So I am working on a small django project and I am having an issue with a foreign key.
I have a model with 2 tables mymodel1 and mymodel2.

```
#Models.py
class Mymodel1(moels.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  blurb = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  
 class Mymodel2(moels.Model):
  name = models.ForeignKey(Mymdoel1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  somethingelse = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

my urls pass in the id from Mymodel1 and my template returns the data but I also want the template to return the data from my model2

```
def get_details(request ,id):
if User.is_authenticated:
    try:
        single_record = Mymodle1.objects.get(id=id)
        details = Mymodel2.objects.get(id=single_record.name)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    context = {
        'single_asset': single_asset,
        'details': details,
    }
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context=context)
else:
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

but I cannot get the view to return the details.

Comment: Just a note your `details` query search looks wrong, you are searching an ID. This: `details = Mymodel2.objects.get(id=single_record.name)` should be more like `details = Mymodel2.objects.get(name=single_record)` you have the `name` attr as an FK, so you need to assign the right model to it

Comment: That worked I was trying that buy using single_record.name and getting an error thank you.

Comment: No worries, I am glad you got your solution, I will post an answer so we can close this question for the records

Answer (score 1):

As we noted from comments, you were not calling your `details` query correctly here:

`details = Mymodel2.objects.get(id=single_record.name)`

The reason was because you were querying the `id` of the model (which in almost every case is a number, int, big int, etc...) with the attribute of the record's `.name` such as: `id=single_record.name` this cannot work.

To fix this you can look at your model `FK` relationship names for the attributes between `Mymodel1` and `Mymodel2`. You can see that`Mymodel2` has an `FK` attribute `name` for `Mymodel1`

In that instance if you call your posted `single_record` like so:

`single_record = Mymodle1.objects.get(id=id)`

Since `Mymodel1` has the attr `name` in `Mymodel2` for the `FK` relationship you would find them by altering your `details` query to this:

`details = Mymodel2.objects.get(name=single_record)`

Or if you want to use `id` (assuming your pk is named `id`):

`details = Mymodel2.objects.get(name__id=single_record.id)`

**Note in most instances it may be easier to use Django's built-in `pk` attribute to automate the selection of the primary key.**

Or you can use the reverse relationship for `Mymodel1` to `Mymodel2`. Django, by default gives you a `related_name` as the ModelName, in lower, followed by `_set`, so since you have no related name you can do:

`details = single_record.mymodel2_set.all()`